# Configure proxy for git on mac

Tags: macos, mac, proxy, git, http

How can I see in mac the proxy configuration on my machine ( Not the ui) My friend have problem to use our corporate git,
 when he do git clone he get proxy error but in my mac I was able to clone this repo. in the macos UI both configuration are the same https://kb.netgear.com/25191/Configuring-TCP-IP-and-Proxy-Settings-on-Mac-OSX

And maybe we miss something else...

we use in the command line

export http_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.corp:8080

and also

https_proxy=http://proxy.mycompany.corp:8080

without success, any idea ?